# Apply bootstrap class to element at specific screen size

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to apply a CSS class to an HTML element only at a certain screen size when using bootstrap?

One scenario would be to apply `table-sm` to `<table>` when the viewport is below md size.

Currently I have two separate tables with one hidden and one displayed depending on the viewport size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table size (`table-sm`), specifically, is not responsive. However, there are many other Bootstrap classes that do work responsively at specific screen widths ("breakpoints") using media queries.

There are [responsive table classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables) to control the horizontal table scroll, but this doesn't impact the size or spacing inside the table cells.

A simple workaround would be to apply the normal table size to the `.table-sm` class above a certain screen width with a media query.

```
@media (min-width:992px) {
    .table-sm td, .table-sm th {
        padding: .75rem;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/cF7T4TrBe3

Answer (score 0):

with bootstrap, no, you would need to create a css file and use @media to define the height or width you would like the styling to take affect at

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp